# Firebase Realtime database react native not retrieving data

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have implemented @react-native-firebase and it should be integrated in my react native project following the steps in the documentation (adding google-services file + updating build.gradle files ect), however when I try to retrieve data or even set; using any of react native methods (on, once, set)

Function to retrieve data:

```
const handleClick = () => {
const databaseForDefaultApp = firebase
  .database()
  .ref()
  .on('value', snapshot => {
    console.log('Retreiveing data..');
    console.log(snapshot);
  });
```

};

UI with button click:

```
return (
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <View>
    <Button title="Press me" onPress={handleClick} />
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>);
```

Package.json with versions

```
  "dependencies": {
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.6.0",
"@react-native-firebase/database": "^15.6.0",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.1"
```

},

Comment: Which version of Firebase are you using?

Comment: I have added it to the original post (@react-native-firebase/app ^15.6.0) - (@react-native-firebase/database: 15.6.0) - (react-native: 0.70.1)

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No not even errors shows up, i tried catching them but nothing as well.

Comment: Are you sure your `handleClick code is actively using `react-native-firebase`? The syntax for calling the Realtime Database with that starts with `database()` (see [here](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage#references), while yours starts with `firebase.database()` (which the Firebase JavaScript SDK uses)).

Comment: Yes handleClick code is active and should be correct, and as far as i understand you can either import database from the SDK or import 'firebase' and access the firebase.database function from that.